# How to dynamically resize images

Tags: css

Here's the index page. It presents four images, fading each out and replacing it with another, for 12 images altogether. And it works fine on Windows with Computer Monitor.

How do I dynamically resize them for a cell phone?

```
 <style>
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  
}
table     {border-collapse: separate;  border-spacing: 10px 20px;}

table, 
table td;}
  .center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
    @keyframes rotateimgs {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33.33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66.66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    }
}

td {
  position: relative;
  --interval: 5s;/* set this to what you want the fade-in time to be */
}

img.fadeinout {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation-name: rotateimgs;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--interval) * 3);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  opacity: 0;
}

img.fadeinout:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
  position: relative;/* if your images are of different sizes, put this on the tallest */
}
img.fadeinout:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: var(--interval);
  }
img.fadeinout:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--interval) * 2);
  }
 
</style>
   
<body> 
  <table class="center" style="max-width:100%"> 
   
  <tr>
    <td>
        <img class="fadeinout" src="/image1.jpg"/>  
        <img class="fadeinout" src="/image2.jpg"/>  
        <img class="fadeinout" src="/image3.jpg"/> 
    </td>
    
    <td>
       <img class="fadeinout" src="/image4.jpg"/>  
       <img class="fadeinout" src="/image5.jpg"/>  
       <img class="fadeinout" src="/image6.jpg"/> 
    </td>
  </tr>
    
<tr>
  <td> 
     <img class="fadeinout" src= "/image7.jpg"/> 
     <img class="fadeinout" src="/image8.jpg" />  
     <img class="fadeinout" src="/image9.jpg" />     
  </td>
 
  <td>
     <img class="fadeinout" src= "/image10.jpg"/> 
     <img class="fadeinout" src="/image11.jpg"/>  
     <img class="fadeinout" src="/image12.jpg"/>     
  </td>
</tr>
 
</table> 
</body>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is only part of the code. The page has a header file, etc. And yes, sorry for the indentation.

Comment: I think I cleaned the code up.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds obvious, but maybe use media queries so you can set the image dimensions and table layout based on the screen width?

```
 /* Media Query for Mobile Devices */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      table {
        width: 100%;
      }
      img.fadeinout {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
    }
    
    /* Media Query for Tablets */
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
      table {
        width: 70%;
      }
      img.fadeinout {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
    }

    /* Media Query for Desktop */
    @media (min-width: 1025px) {
      table {
        width: 50%;
      }
      img.fadeinout {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but I think that won't work. I think I just need to resize the images based on the screen width. Just a guess.